# How to dynamically override I18n fallbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

So I have set

```
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

but I want to check if a translation exists for a locale and when I do

```
I18n.t("vendor.iso.region.CN", locale: 'yue', default: nil).present?
```

it gives true but the result is the English fallback "China"

how do I skip the fallbacks for this translation call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy:

```
I18n.t("vendor.iso.region.CN", locale: 'yue', default: nil, fallback: false).present?
```